# How to select only the first element of a certain class, not it's grand children

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve something like this

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="item"> <!-- select this -->
      <div class="item"> <!-- not this -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using `first-child` like this -

```css
.parent .child .item:first-child p {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">

    <div class="item">  <!-- select this -->
      <p>This should be changed</p>

      <div class="item">  <!-- not this -->
        <p>This should NOT be changed</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

But it didn't work. Is there any pure CSS way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for the child combinator:

```css
.parent .child > .item > p {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="item">  <!-- select this -->
            <p>This should be changed</p>
        <div class="item">  <!-- not this -->
            <p>This should NOT be changed</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent .child .item:first-child > p {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">

    <div class="item">  <!-- select this -->
      <p>This should be changed</p>

      <div class="item">  <!-- not this -->
        <p>This should NOT be changed</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `:first-of-type` pseudo-class.

> The `:first-of-type` CSS pseudo-class represents the first element of its type among a group of sibling elements.

Here you're selecting the first `div`, and then, the first `p` element.

```css
.parent > .child > .item:first-of-type > p:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">

    <div class="item">  <!-- select this -->
      <p>This should be changed</p>

      <div class="item">  <!-- not this -->
        <p>This should NOT be changed</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```